# Input field not clearing

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field that asks the user for a number then generates a multiplication from 1 - 12 against the number.

```
<input type="text" id="integer" value="100" />
```

if the number entered in the input field is less than 1 and greater than 100, it will alert the user to enter a number between 1 and 100

```
if (integer < 1 || integer > 100) {
          alert(
            "Please enter a valid input \nEnter any number between 1 and 100"
          );}
```

After the alert, the input field should clear.

```
let integer = document.getElementById("integer").value
```

i have tried setting the input value to ""

```
if (integer < 1 || integer > 100) {
          alert(
            "Please enter a valid input \nEnter any number between 1 and 100"
          );
          integer = "";}
```

but the input isn't clearing.

Comment: You are just changing the value of the variable `integer`, not the value field. You need to write `document.getElementById("integer").value = ''`.

Comment: I wrote another line just like you  mentioned but still nothing. I have that line immediately after the alert. should I place it somewhere else for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my mind (without testing), while doing

`let integer = document.getElementById("integer").value`

You're not referencing the "value", but deep-copy the value, so either to clear input again do querySearch by calling:

`document.getElementById("integer").value = ""`

or make variable reference whole object like:

`let integer = document.getElementById("integer")`

and then use it like `integer.value = "";`

EDIT EXAMPLE:

```js
let testInput = document.getElementById("testInput");
let testBtn = document.getElementById("testBtn");
let testOutput = document.getElementById("testOutput");
let testOutput2 = document.getElementById("testOutput2");

testBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  testOutput.innerHTML = testInput.value;
  
  if (testInput.value > 0 && testInput.value < 100)
    testOutput2.innerHTML = "good";
  else
    testOutput2.innerHTML = 'bad';
  
  testInput.value = "";
});
```

```html
<div style="padding: 15px; border: 1px solid gray;">
  <input type="number" id="testInput" />
  <br />
  <button id="testBtn" type="button">Display and clear</button>
  <br /><br />
  <p>output value: <span id="testOutput"></span> | <span id="testOutput2"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: In the first step they _are_ referencing the value, but when 'clearing' they are referencing a new value again.

Comment: I've tried both methods but its still not clearing. I even tried to use integer.textContent but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I've provided example that's working in "primitive way". If this won't resolve your issue, could you please provide your code in form of some sandbox app. This would help debugging.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked! Now the input is clearing!

Answer (score -4):

`<input type="text" id="integer" min="1" max= "100" value="100" />`

Comment: I'd like the input to clear to a blank field if the number doesn't meet that requirement.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to post this as an answer?